# How to override or inherit a z3c.form widget?

Tags: widget, overriding, plone, dexterity, z3c.form

I need to override the behavior of the widget assigned to a field on a [z3c.form](https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.form) (specifically the widget used for a `schema.Bool` field like the one declared below) to change the way the widget mode works under different conditions:

```py
from plone.autoform.interfaces import IFormFieldProvider
from plone.supermodel import model
from zope import schema
from zope.interface import provider

@provider(IFormFieldProvider)
class IGoogleNews(model.Schema):
    """Behavior interface to add some Google News features."""

    standout_journalism = schema.Bool(
        title=_(u'Standout Journalism'),
        required=False,
    )

    news_keywords = schema.Tuple(
        title=_(u'Keywords'),
        value_type=schema.TextLine(),
        required=False,
    )
```

Comment: You're digging in hell ;-) It's probably easier to write your own widget inheriting from the original bool widget. Overriding a widget is no that easy,  Without providing a new interface on the form, or field itself. Afaik You can only override the bool widget generally.

Comment: in fact, that was my initial  idea :-) do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is example code derived from [ftw.datepicker](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.datepicker) widget.

In widget.py:

```
# This widget has a plone integration, so we take this one as base
from plone.z3cform.widget import SingleCheckBoxWidget
from z3c.form.interfaces import DISPLAY_MODE
from z3c.form.interfaces import ISingleCheckBoxWidget
from zope.interface import implementsOnly
from zope.component import adapter
from z3c.form.interfaces import IFormLayer
from z3c.form.interfaces import IFieldWidget
from z3c.form.widget import FieldWidget


class IMyBoolWidget(ISingleCheckBoxWidget):
    """Marker interface"""


class MyBoolWidget(SingleCheckBoxWidget)
    implementsOnly(IMyBoolWidget)

    display_template = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/keyword_display.pt')
    input_template = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/keyword_input.pt')
    hidden_template = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/keyword_hidden.pt')
    disabled_template = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/disabled_hidden.pt') 

    def update(self):
       super(MyBoolWidget, self).update()

    if self.disable_widget():
        # Change widget to display mode
        self.mode = 'my_own_disabled_mode'

    def disable_widget(self):
        # Figure out if the widget should enabled or not.

   def render(self):
       if self.mode == INPUT_MODE:
            return self.input_template(self)
        elif self.mode == DISPLAY_MODE:
            return self.display_template(self)
        elif self.mode == HIDDEN_MODE:
            return self.hidden_template(self)
        elif self.mode == 'my_own_disabled_mode'
            return self.disabled_template(self)
        raise NotImplementedError(
            'Mode: "{0}" not supported'.format(self.mode))

# Following the patterns of z3c widget and create a widget factory.
# This is not necessary in this case, since there are no additional params.

@adapter(IMyBoolWidget, IFormLayer)
@implementer(IFieldWidget)
def MyBoolWidgetFactory(field, request, config=None):
    """IFieldWidget factory for..."""
    return FieldWidget(field, MyBoolWidget(request))

MyBoolFieldWidget = MyBoolWidgetFactory
```

Register using zcml (configure.zcml):

```
    <adapter factory=".widget.MyBoolWidgetFactory" />
```

Use the widget for your boolean field.

```
from plone.autoform.interfaces import IFormFieldProvider
from plone.supermodel import model
from zope import schema
from zope.interface import provider
from plone.directives import form
from wherever.the.widget.is import widget MyBoolFieldWidget


@provider(IFormFieldProvider)
class IGoogleNews(model.Schema):
    """Behavior interface to add some Google News features."""

    form.widget('standout_journalism', MyBoolFieldWidget)
    standout_journalism = schema.Bool(
        title=_(u'Standout Journalism'),
        required=False,
    )

    news_keywords = schema.Tuple(
        title=_(u'Keywords'),
        value_type=schema.TextLine(),
        required=False,
    )
```

Following this approach I created several widgets,
For example also a [KeywordWidget](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.keywordwidget)

On the plus side:

- Usually small and minimalistic
- easy to use

malus:

- You need to manually apply it everywhere you want.

The example does not include any templates, you may get them `from z3c.form` or plone.z3cform.*

This approach is pretty straight forward and does not use the all the components a widget usually does. Like register a widget template for every mode, etc.

Comment: thank you! I'll test this and give you feedback in the following days.